# How do I securely browse the internet (Network path, MITM attacks, rerouting the network)

Tags: networking, router

All the local ISPs that I could have an account with, impose many restrictions against an average user, and to be precise and brief, a simple right like surfing the web securely and without any poking noses is almost impossible.

Now I have an idea which I am not sure if it is practical:
 I ran `tracert` command for different domain names and IPs, and all the time there is these three specific IPs showing up, and I think these IPs are responsible for the censorship and traffic control. Now, my question is:

**Is it possible to somehow reroute my network connection or somehow force my data packets to go through a different route, or not?**

What I have done so far, and the current situation:

- Most of the VPNs are not reachable, and are filtered out.
- OpenVPN, SecurityKiss, Cyberghost, and similar applications do not work
- Tried to force my connection through TOR and different proxy servers, but either the speed drops dramatically or proxy tries to log my activities.
- VPNGate works, and all its VPN partners work very fine, and even connection to the website of the application is possible without any problems, which leads us to the conclusion that either this application and its producers work for the government or it is not considered that dangerous for them. Cause you don't even need to put an HTTPS at the beginning of the web address to open the site.

Comment: Jacob, while I'm sure many of us appreciate your frustration - questions asking to bypass security and of questionable legality are off topic here.

Comment: @Jacob Rabinsun The question will also likely be closed on SuperUser.  Posting on multiple sites is generaly unwelcome and as noted, bypassing security is not usually an accepted topic.

Comment: The only reason, why I am doing this is to have secure and private online activity. It is not only a healthy and educational networking activity, which could teach us many things, it also could contribute to the security and privacy of our information. So, it is education, security, privacy, and anonymity that matter to me.

Comment: And about asking the same question on multiple sites, I am totally sorry. I wasn't aware that we better not to ask on different sites.

Comment: FYI, the question was removed from SuperUser.com, my apologies.

Comment: You need a different country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you get a dialup connection to someone outside of your country, there is no way you can tell your packets to take a different route. Routing decisions are made on every router, and it is obviously not a good idea to let anyone decide where they want their packets to go, you tell the router your final destination, and it, and the routers between you and there will ensure it arrives (or not), based upon decisions that the administrators of those routers made.

Have you tried ssh tunnels? You could obtain a low cost hosted server outside of your country, and tunnel your traffic through it.

Comment: Thankyou, I am going to read about it and how it should be implemented and then try that too. Seems pretty cool. I'll be back with the news after I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the TOR Browser was made for this. I'm trying to make this a long enough answer not to get made into a comment so I'll give a brief description of Tor. Basically, it routes your packets through the Tor network, so it will be slower (but then again, your on dialup so....), but *almost* untraceable. Here, take a peek at [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/)

**Update**

For the sake of a complete answer I'll also suggest the possibility of a proxy chain, which is sort of what Tor does already but it's not something you need Tor for. Basically it's a 'chain' of machines that you route your web requests through.

Comment: Thank you, both for your interest and answer. I have already tried TOR. There are some problems though: 1- Speed is very low. 2- It becomes unstable sometimes. 3- The ISP has an amazing control over TOR, they enable access to it whenever they like and they disable access to TOR nodes if they want, in this case even bridges won't be effective.